# Is ffmpeg usable with audio loudness normalization?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, noise, spotify

I need to convert some CD mastered audio to be sent to Spotify.

Spotify does not prefer CD mastered but it has some loudness suggestions:

( https://artists.spotify.com/en/help/article/loudness-normalization )

```
    Target the loudness level of your master at -14dB integrated LUFS 
and keep it below -1dB TP (True Peak) max. This is best for lossy 
formats (Ogg/Vorbis and AAC) and makes sure no extra distortion’s 
introduced in the transcoding process.

    If your master’s louder than -14dB integrated LUFS, make sure 
it stays below -2dB TP (True Peak) to avoid extra distortion. This 
is because louder tracks are more susceptible to extra distortion 
in the transcoding process.
```

Is this doable with ffmpeg?  Any other program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure it can!

You can do this with the loudnorm filter:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af loudnorm=I=-14:LRA=11:TP=-1 output.mp3`

I = integrated loudness

LRA = loudness range

TP = true peak

It seems that you can get better results by running a second pass. You can do it manually like mentioned [here](https://bytesandbones.wordpress.com/2017/03/16/audio-nomalization-with-ffmpeg-using-loudnorm-ebur128-filter/)
or by using [ffmpeg-normalize,](https://github.com/slhck/ffmpeg-normalize/) which can do it in one go.

Example with same parameters:

`ffmpeg-normalize input.flac -t -14 -lrt 11 -tp -1 output.flac`

Comment: wow, I'm totally speachless. ffmpeg ftw!

Comment: @AnttiRytsölä truly one software to rule them all

Comment: Current (04/2022) command line is

ffmpeg-normalize input.flac -t -14 -lrt 11 -tp -1 -ext flac -c:a flac -o output.flac