# Loudnorm filter in ffmpeg incorrectly normalizes some audios

Tags: ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg with the Loudnorm Filter in two pass.

Loudnorm Filter is incorrectly normalizing the integrated output in some audio files.

I set the target value at -11.0 LUFS and the True Peak value at -1.0 dBTP, however some audios the output value has the volume lowered even more.

Image of Filter results:
[image]

Why in Audios 3 and 4, the values are even smaller than the input value, since I set the target to -11.0 LUFS?

Comment: If the input is highly dynamic & true peak is higher than your desired value, then it has no choice but to turn it all down, resulting in lower LUFS. Your target offset is huge. Is this pure audio [music] or video? Video you ought to be aiming for -24LUFS to approximate broadcast standards.

Comment: @Tetsujin the file is pure audio[music]. So what should I do so that the low LUFS audios are correctly normalized according to the target value -11.0LUFS?. The other audios were normalized correctly and I need these audios to be at the same level as the others, otherwise there will be a volume difference when playing all of them.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with ffmpeg, I would normally do this in a DAW or Myriad batch processor, but what's your command line to do this? I wonder if that can be tweaked to be more aggressive. All I really know about it is this - http://johnriselvato.com/ffmpeg-how-to-normalize-audio/ which is not exactly comprehensive & https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#loudnorm which is also a bit dry.

Comment: Did you do a single or a two pass normalization? Please edit your question with the specific commands you've used

Comment: See [my recent answer regarding loudnorm](https://superuser.com/a/1705714/718047), specifically the links mentioning the second pass.